# Can a FOIA request reveal how many times I have entered the U.S. as a citizen?

Tags: immigration, foia

I know there are certain restrictions on personal information for FOIA requests, and verification of such is required beforehand. Even so, should this information be accessible? If so, to which agency do I submit the request?

Additionally, I known non-citizens can request and receive this information, but I have not found examples of citizens requesting this information, as I am.

Comment: The agency will be Customs and Border Protection.  I believe they do retain the records and they will disclose them in response to a request, but I don't know much more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 3):

As a US Citizen, you don't get a I-94 recording of entries and exits but :

The FOIA site of the [CBP](https://www.cbp.gov/site-policy-notices/foia/records), mentions

> Information Regarding Entry and Exit
>
> Note: CBP does not have records on the entry and exit of persons arriving or departing the U.S. before 1982.

To be filled with CBP

However, this doesn't mentions if this is only applicable to Aliens or US Citizens are included or not. But this [CBP help page](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1729?language=en_US) mentions travel records for US Citizens